# Checking if file exists Java

Tags: java, file, exists

I'm trying to check to see if a Hashmap file exists.  The file is created and showing in my default package in Eclipse.  If it exists I'm going to read in the hashmap, if it doesn't I want to create a new file.  Currently the code isn't seeing the created file for some reason.

```
public UrlCache() throws UrlCacheException {
    File hmFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\hashMapFile.properties");
    System.out.println("Working Directory = "+ hmFile);


    if(hmFile.exists()) { 
        System.out.println("File Exists");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("File does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you `default package in Eclipse` is different from `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly check if file exists or not by using exists() method createNewFile() method will do it,

createNewFile() will create a new file if it does not exist and return true but if that file exists createNewFile() will return false

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\hashMapFile.properties");
if(f.createNewFile()) {
   System.out.println("Created new Hashmap file");
}
```

We are not writing the else portion here because there is no need according to the requirement you have mentioned.

Comment: 2 issues.  It seems to require an IOException for f.createNewFile(), which then also requires it to be thrown in the main class if I add it.   The second issue is that it just doesn't work.  No file is created.

Comment: While working with IO you will need to handle some exceptions to handle negative scenarios. For your second problem, you should look for the path on which you are trying save the hashMapFile.properties file it might be wrong, just try to pass some hard coded path like File f = new File("/home/local/naresh.j" + "/hashMapFile.properties")